# Add a sub-collection to a field; i.e. add a grand-child sub-collection to a collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

The documentation shows how to add a sub-collection as a direct child of a document.

```
collection01
  doc01
    field01
    collection02     <----- winning!
```

We add that `collection02` with this code:

```
// create the collection
await firestore.collection('collection01').doc('doc01').set({
  field01: {}
});

// add the sub collection
await firestore
  .collection('collection01').doc('doc01')
  .collection('collection02').doc('doc02').set({});
```

How, if at all, can we add a sub-collection as a grandchild like this:

```
collection01
  doc01
    field01
      collection03     <----- how do we do this?
    collection02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document fields can't have nested subcollections.  You can only nest subcollections organized under a document itself.  The document doesn't have to exist ahead of time.